# Add selected value to Select2 when multiple is false

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 to search for people, and then select the person you want from a list. It all works fine:

```
Task.ConfigureAssignee = function (objId) {
var sectionID = SubSectionID || 0;

$(objId).select2({
    placeholder: 'Type names of people...',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    multiple: true,
    width: '520px',
    id: function (obj) {
        return obj.ID;
    },
    ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        url: "/webservices/globalwebservice.asmx/TaskAssignSearch",
        data: function (term) {
            return JSON.stringify({ q: term, sectionId: sectionID, taskType: TaskPageType });
        },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        results: function (data, page) {
            var ids = $(objId).select2("val");
            data.d = $(data.d).filter(function () {
                var id = $(this)[0].ID;

                return (ids.indexOf(id) == -1);
            });

            return { results: data.d };
        }
    },
    formatResult: Task.FormatPersonSearchResult, 
    formatSelection: Task.PersonForSelection,
    initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        var data = [];
        var ids = []
        if ($(element).val().length > 0) {
            var items = JSON.parse($(element).val())

            $(items).each(function () {
                var id = this.ID;
                var name = this.Name;
                data.push({ ID: id, Name: name });
                ids.push(id);
            });

        }
        $(objId).select2("val", ids.join(","));
        callback(data);
    }
})
}
```

Sometimes at a button click I want to add a specific person to the select2 via javascript:

```
$("#txtTaskAssignee").select2('destroy');
$('#txtTaskAssignee').val("[{\"ID\":265,\"Name\":\"Kate Evans\"}]");
Task.ConfigureAssignee('#txtTaskAssignee');
```

Again, this works fine. I dont want to allow multiple selections however and when I switch to single mode then the selected value isn't set.

Any ideas?